# Laravel responce returns empty but when I print and ran the query in db it works

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

This is the query code that I am using please look and help me out. I would really appreciate it

```
DB::table('position as p') -> addSelect(\DB::raw(
        'p.*,(SELECT name from user where user.id=p.user_id) as name'
    )) 
    -> addSelect(\DB::raw(
        'DATE_FORMAT(p.created_at,"%H:%i") as time'
    ))
    -> whereRaw($wr) 
    -> whereRaw(
        "(p.id =(SELECT id FROM position WHERE position.user_id=p.user_id AND Date(position.created_at)='".$date.
        "' order by position.id asc limit 0,1) Or p.id =(SELECT id FROM position WHERE position.user_id=p.user_id AND Date(position.created_at)='".$date.
        "' order by position.id desc limit 0,1))") 
    -> orderBy("p.user_id", "asc") - > orderBy("p.id", 'asc') - > get();
```

Comment: Can you show us how the code where you return the response?

Comment: I just  put $start_end= DB::table('position as p')... then rest of the query and $start_date is empty